# Telerik MVC ScriptRegistrar duplicating javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, telerik, telerik-mvc

I am attempting to register some javascript in my view, and I seem to be having an issue.  In my master page, at the bottom I have:

```
@(
    Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
        .OnDocumentReady(@<text>
            // Open the hidden window when the feedback-link is clicked
            $('#feedback-link').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                $('#FeedbackWindow').data('tWindow').center().open();
            });
        </text>)
)
```

In my view, I want some view specific javascript, so I have:

```
@(Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().OnDocumentReady(
    @<text>
        // Upon contact selection change, update the contact sidebar summary
        $('#contactlist').change(function() {
            alert('Selected id' + $(this).val());
        });
    </text>)
)
```

Unfortunately, this is causing my view's javascript from being declared both in the MVC view, and in my master page when the final page is rendered.  How can I get this to only register the script once?

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/scriptregistrar-creates-two-jquery-blocks-in-razor-view.aspx#1626423

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I said in my [forum reply](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-mvc/general/scriptregistrar-creates-two-jquery-blocks-in-razor-view.aspx#1626423) the ScriptRegistrar is being output twice because told so. The `@()` Razor expression will output its contents whereas `@{ }` will be executed. In your case you need to use `@{ }` for the specific script:

```
@{ Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar().OnDocumentReady(
    @<text>
        // Upon contact selection change, update the contact sidebar summary
        $('#contactlist').change(function() {
            alert('Selected id' + $(this).val());
        });
    </text>);
}
```

Also note that the `@{ }` block requires a semi-colon.

Comment: Ohhh, that makes sense, I was reading the posts on it, and I kept reading it as `@{ }` should be over the master pages.  Guess I was getting it backwards :).  I'll give this a shot when I get home.